# How i can access to JSON data?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have created a dynamic array and then,  i  convert  it  to  json object. The code is the follows:

```
$array_D1[]="";
$array_D2[]="";
$array_to_send[]="";

$array_D1[$CapaEnviar][] = $fila['test_name'];
$array_D2[]=$seleccio_content;
$array_D2[]=$id_capa;
$array_D2[]=$pagina;
$array_D2[]=$idtest;
$array_D2[]=$valor_org;
$array_D2[]=$valor_eval;
$array_D2[]=$valor_test;

$array_to_send=array('data1' => $array_D1, 'data2' => $array_D2);

echo json_encode($array_to_send,true);
```

This code is a AJAX response for an AJAX request. I don't know how i can access JSON data  from jquery.

i need to acces the values from "data1" and "data2"

Comment: You forgot to include the client side code. We don't know how you are fetching the data.

Comment: PHP defaults to sending a `Content-Type: text/html` response header. You need to override that with the `header()` function if you aren't outputting HTML.

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '#seleccio_test,#seleccio_test2', function(){

 var capaTEST;
 var pagina="show_test_prova.php";
  $.ajax({
     async:false,    
     cache:false,   
     dataType:"json",   
     type: "POST",   
     url: pagina,
     data: "dades_test="+obtenirTest(),
     success:  function(obj){ 


      var con= $("#KTK");
      con.html(obj.data2);       },
  beforeSend:function(){},
  error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){alert("Error: "+textStatus);}
 })
 
})`

Comment: That looks like it should work. What's the problem?

Comment: Try parse the json JSON.parse(obj);

Comment: @JohnnyJohn — No. It says `dataType:"json"`. jQuery will parse it before populating `obj`.

Comment: the client side code is a simple AJAX request , i want to access  each one of data that are  there  both data1 as  data2, it's clear?

Comment: @riztak — No, it isn't clear. You're just repeating your goal without explaining what the problem is. The code appears to already successfully access data2. It should be obvious how to access data1. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: ok, wait a moment i will do some test .

Comment: This  works good:  alert(JSON.stringify(obj.data1));, both data1  and data2 gives an array , what i want is to loop in order to obteain the datas from eah one .

Comment: i need to acces each one of value inside data1 and data2

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what's hard about this. The others are right that you probably should add:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

to your php file before your echo statement.

Assuming that you can access the php with a url, say, http://blah.com/test.php, you can...

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'post', //or 'get'
        url: 'http://blah.com/test.php'
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.dir(data.data1);
    console.dir(data.data2);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.dir(jqXHR);
    console.dir(textStatus);
});
```

Obviously, you can replace the body of the callback with whatever processing you want.